# android wifimamger to scan all avalible networks

Tags: android, wifimanager

I went to make an app that scan all the available networks in Android phone  app have to scan the networks again and again with the delay of 5s run for 3 minutes fetch the level values    and give me the average of level value as the output. any help?

```
handler = new Handler();
          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  task_repeart();
              }
          }, 5000);
public void task_repeart( )
    {
        repaert++;
        getWifiNetworksList(); // getWifiNetworksList does not give any output in this way other wise this function works perfect 
        if (repaert < 3  ){ // just for the test purposing i am call  getWifiNetworksList() just 3 time
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  task_repeart();
              }
          }, 5000);
        }
    }
 private void getWifiNetworksList(){  
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(); 
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION); 
        final WifiManager wifiManager =  (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);; 
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){ 
            @SuppressLint("UseValueOf") 

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults(); 
                sb.append("\n Number Of Wifi connections :" + " " +scanList.size()+"\n\n");  
                for(int i = 0; i < scanList.size(); i++){
                    sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ". "); 
                    sb.append((scanList.get(i)).toString()); 
                    sb.append("\n\n"); }  tv.setText(sb);  
            }  
            },filter); 
        wifiManager.startScan(); 
        }
```

Comment: yes. A) learn programming B) learn Android programming. C) When you get stuck with a programming problem ask a real question!

Comment: i have already study Android wifimanger, from this i am able to scan the network available but i am not able to scan networks after 5s.Set the delay of 5s i have used thread.sleep , handler , scheduler to make delay of 5s but it does not work

Comment: Please put at least one of your not working solutions in your question. I would have answered with a solution using handler, but If you already tried that and it didn't work, there isn't much sense in trying again, right? No seriously, post your handler solution, we'll work is out.

Comment: i have submit the code , PLZ check tell me the reasons why my code is not working